# Помогите с правилом NGINX

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Всем привет, написал правило для nginx, не работает, выдает ошибку

```
/var/www/api/api_users/index.php/main/get" failed (20: Not a directory)
```

Мой конфиг

```
server {
    server_name api.auto.as;

    root /var/www/api/;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)\.(.*)$ /api_$1/index.php/main/$2?$query_string break;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

Запрос: http://api.auto.as/users.get

Подскажите решение.

Comment: очевидно же, что /api_user/index.php/main/get не попадает в `~* \.php$`

Comment: как тогда правильно написать?

Answer (score 1):

Простое решение

```
location ~* \.php {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Правильное решение

```
location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z]+).([a-zA-Z]+)$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /api_$1/index.php/main/$2$is_args$args;

    # может fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
    # может fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             /api_$1/index.php/main/$2$is_args$args;
}
```

Правильное решение не допускает неоднозначностей и с ним легко жить, сложность лишь в том, что я не знаю какой именно из параметров, передающихся бекенду (fastcgi_param), нужно менять. Нужно курить [доку](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html), [вики](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/).